# Pass an MFC control to a thread or pass an handle?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, user-interface, mfc

I've been reading somewhere that it is safer to pass an MFC ui control to a thread as an handle rather than to pass a pointer to the control.

Option 1 - pass a pointer to static text:

```
TestDialog  dlg1;
::_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &tSetTextByPointer, &dlg1.m_StaticText, 0, NULL);
dlg1.DoModal();

UINT WINAPI tSetTextByPointer(LPVOID arg)
{
    CStatic * pStaticText = static_cast<CStatic*>(arg);
    Sleep(3000);
    pStaticText->SendMessage(WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)L"text");

    return 0;
}
```

Option 2 - pass an handle :

```
TestDialog  dlg1;
::_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &tSetTextByHandle, &(dlg1.m_StaticText.m_hWnd), 0, NULL);
dlg1.DoModal();

UINT WINAPI tSetTextByHandle(LPVOID arg)
{
    HWND * pTextHandle = static_cast<HWND*>(arg);
    Sleep(3000);
    ::SendMessage(*pTextHandle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)L"text");

    return 0;
}
```

Should I really prefer using handles when accessing controls by multiple threads?
Or is it enough to rely on SendMessage() to cover the thread-safety matter when accessing the control?

Comment: Option 2 is not really passing a handle, it's passing a pointer to your static control's handle member.  So some of the hazards remain. The safety in using handles is that they can be passed around by value, without the possibility of accessing memory from a destroyed object.  So pass the handle's value through _beginthreadex as static_cast<void*>(dlg1.m_StaticText.m_hWnd) and in your thread function, get the HWND back with HWND hwStatic = static_cast<HWND>(arg).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you shouldn't call UI directly from worker threads. For many good reasons.

But if you do need this then use of raw HWNDs is safer. Otherwise you should check if `pStaticText->SendMessage` method is thread safe.

If you are on VS2010 and above I would suggest to use this approach:
http://www.terrainformatica.com/2011/01/c0x-running-code-in-gui-thread-from-worker-threads/